# saving SQL backup / dump on remote location

Tags: mysql

I would like to backup / dump my SQL (mysql - InnoDB or XtraDB depending if I will use Oracle's Mysql or MariaDB) database regularly.

Now, my hosting for the beginning will be 60 GB on SSD so it will soon fill with pictures and rows of tables, so the space is limited.

I want to dump my database safely and securely and non-intrusively (meaning not stressing out the server when doing it) and **I NEED** the file to be saved say on my local Win7 desktop, not on the server.

mysqldump does the trick, but fills up space on the server, and if my database will grow to 20 GB and I have 20 GB of pictures, the dump will fill out the remaining space or maybe would not fit at all.

so what are the ways to remotely save the dump (not on the same server) ?

i figure I can save / dump my tables from phpMyAdmin for sure, but when the tables get to 2 GB or 10 GB...don't know for sure if it works anymore (millions of rows)

thanks!

Comment: admins, pls move this to the appropriate server if you think it's not here that I should post. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have *remote* access to your database server, this is only a matter of using [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) with the correct [*host* option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_host) from a machine with enough disk space to hold your backup.

```
# if your database server has DNS name :
mysqldump -h my.database-server.local ... 

# if you access your database server by its IPv4 address
mysqldump -h 192.168.0.22 ...
```

Or do I totally missed the point here?

Comment: so you're saying I can do a mysqldump from my laptop Ubuntu linux box by providing -h server_address where server_address is the name of my main server where I have the database hosted ? that's great! thx.